# adding a user installing rabbitmq with chef

Tags: rabbitmq, chef-infra

successfully installed the rabbitmq server with the management plugin:

```
  version = '4.5.1'
  run_list = [ "recipe[rabbitmq::default@#{version}]",
               "recipe[rabbitmq::mgmt_console@#{version}]",
               "recipe[rabbitmq::user_management@#{version}]"]
```

attributes:

```
default['rabbitmq']['enabled_users'] =
  [{ :name => 'guest', :password => 'guest', :rights =>
    [{ :vhost => nil, :conf => '.*', :write => '.*', :read => '.*' }]
  },
   { :name => 'fake_user', :password => 'fake_user', :tag => 'administrator', :rights =>
       [{ :vhost => nil, :conf => '.*', :write => '.*', :read => '.*' }]
   }]
default['rabbitmq']['disabled_users'] = []


default['rabbitmq']['loopback_users'] = ['fake_user']
```

verified it in the  /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config file `{loopback_users, [<<"fake_user">>]},`

the user is installed but I can't log in the management console and can't access it with the credentials .

even tried via the console:

```
rabbitmqctl delete_user fake_user
rabbitmqctl add_user fake_user fake_user
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / fake_user ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `fake_user` in your [`loopback_users`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) you can only authenticate locally, not from the management interface.

Try with this to allow remote authentication:

```ruby
default['rabbitmq']['loopback_users'] = []
```